# What Should be the Form Action When creating Facebook canvas app?

Tags: php, facebook, canvas, facebook-php-sdk

I am creating Facebook canvas app.

App is located in `example.com/test/index.php`.

This is a part of code.

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal information:</legend>
    Enter Text:<br>
    <input type="text" name="FirstText" id="ftext" name="ftext">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST["ftext"]))
  {
            ----------
            ----------
  }
?>
```

I tired action as "index.php", "https://example.com/test/index.php" and  "https://example.com/test/".

But any of above did not work. What should be the form action?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't get a 404 error then not the `action` attribute is the problem.

i would suggest you print information about you variables (before and after the post)

```
<pre><?php print_r($_POST); ?></pre>
<pre><?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?></pre>
<pre><?php print_r($_SERVER); ?></pre>
```

this should help you understand de problem and debug it.